# Java: Why is my code reading and saving the file path and not the actual contents of the file?

Tags: java, arraylist, java.util.scanner

I have been working on this method to open a file and read its contents into an ArrayList. For some reason, it is storing the file path in the ArrayList and not the file contents!

```
text = new MyArrayList<>();
try (Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(fileName).getAbsolutePath())) {
  while (s.hasNext()) {
    text.add(s.next());
  }
}
```

Could you help me figure out where I am making the mistake, thank you!

P.S. **MyArrayList is my own implementation of the ArrayList, it works as a ArrayList.**

Comment: Try executing `System.out.println(new File(fileName).getAbsolutePath());` and see what happens.

Comment: You are creating the Scanner object with a String value. The `getAbsolutePath()` method returns a String, so that is the object that is read by the scanner. Get rid of that statement and just pass the `File` to the `Scanner`.

Comment: I think because you call `getAbsolutePath` on the `File` object and that returns a string, not a `File`.  Just use the `File` object.

Comment: Note that `Scanner` has a constructor overload that accepts a `String`.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner(java.lang.String)  That's the constructor that's being called in your code.

Comment: I wanted to make it so that I could access the file even if it was not in the directory by using that method, and for some reason without it I would just get a filenotfound exception

Comment: The File object doesn't actually open the file.  The Scanner does.

Comment: In the code you posted, it's not opening the file at all; it's just returning the absolute path from your file name.

Comment: I am not too familiar with file io in java, this is actually my first project with it, so I would like to ask how should I fix it?

Comment: I guess you could do this: `new Scanner( new File( new File(fileName).getAbsolutePath() ) )`

Comment: So File is a object, and these are just methods for that object, omg I was really overthinking this, thank you

Comment: that didnt really work, whelps I dont know why but it keeps throwing the file not found exception

Comment: Refer to [Basic I/O](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/) lesson in Oracle's Java tutorials.

Comment: (1) When you pass in the `fileName`, are you passing in an absolute path, or a relative path? (2) If it's a relative path, what's your Java environment's working dir? If you're running this via an IDE, the run configuration should have that as an option somewhere. Make sure that the relative path is relative to that dir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we work with files in java, we have to be very specific about the file we are talking about.

There could be more than one files with the same name in your entire file structure, how would java decide which file it needs to consider. We have below two options

1. Working with absolute path - First option is to provide the absolute path to Java program, so that it can simply create an object using that path.
2. Working with relative path - When we are working with relative path, java only searches the file in the classpath, which is by default current working directory, that is, your projects root folder.

In case you want to use the relative path, make sure it lies in the classpath.

[image: Reference Image]

Otherwise make sure to provide the absolute path to the program.

Giving any filename to the program and expecting java to find out the absolute file path is not the right.

Needless to say that your Scanner Object has to be correct.